# Convert or resave textfile in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, powershell

I'm working with ESL and the articles comes every day in a folder with all articles that has been updated, then the software reads the file, converts it to xml\layout and an AP send the information to the ESL so it will update..

[image]

In this new store that is being installed, som articles has a NUL value in the name-field, and it will stop the import because the software converting dont like it.. it can easy be fixed be re-saving the file in notepad, dont even need to edit, just resave and NUL is gone.

My plan is to fix it while moving the file from one folder to another before importing, and at the same time convert or resave it.

Is this easy done in vb.net? I have a windows service that can watch a folder and move all new files to the right location.

```
        For Each f In Directory.GetFiles(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("NetworkPath").ToString, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        If File.Exists(f) Then
            File.Copy(f, System.IO.Path.Combine((System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("LocalPath").ToString), System.IO.Path.GetFileName(f)), True)

            Dim Buffert As String
            Buffert = File.ReadAllText(f)
            Buffert = Buffert.Replace(vbNullChar, "")
            File.WriteAllText(f, Buffert)

            File.Delete(f)
        End If
    Next
```

In Powershell

```
(Get-Content "C:\test\1.I1") -replace "`0", "" | Set-Content "C:\test\1a.I1"
```

This was enough to remove all NUL-values..

Does anyone have a great idea?

Problem solved and code updated if anyone with the problem reads this.

Comment: Roughly what size are the files to be converted?

Comment: Presumably you could call `File.ReadAllText`, `String.Replace` and `File.WriteAllText`.

Comment: The biggest files are ~30-40MB with 100,000 lines, but sometimes only one row.

Comment: @jmcilhinney ,thanks I will try that

Comment: @jmcilhinney ,that worked thanks